# Split a list into two - one with every second element, and another with all the rest

Tags: scheme

I am writing a recursive function `(split L)`
that takes list `L`, and returns a new list
containing two sub lists with the first sub list containing every second element in `L`
and the second list containing the remaining elements not in the first sub list.

Here
are examples of how
split
should work:

```
(split ‘(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) )  ( (1 3 5 7) (2 4 6 8))
(split ‘(cat bird dog horse mouse pig tiger gerbil cow) )
( (cat dog mouse tiger cow) (bird horse pig gerbil))
```

Now here is my attempt:

```
(define split
    (lambda (L)
        (if
            (null? L)
            '()
            (list (first L) (second L))
        )
    )
)

(define first
    (lambda (L)
        (if
            (null? L)
            '()
            (cond
                (
                    (null? (cdr L)) 
                    (car L)
                )
                (
                    #t 
                    (cons
                        (car L)
                        (first (cdr (cdr L)))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

(define second
    (lambda (L)
        (if
            (null? L)
            '()
        )
        (cond
            (
                (null? (cdr L))
                '()
            )
            (cons
                (car (cdr L))
                (second (cdr (cdr L)))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But instead of the expected result I get:

For `(split '(1234))` I get `((1234)())`. 
For `(first '(1234))` I get `(1234)`. 
For `(second '(1234))` I get `()`.

Comment: With every closing parentheses on a newline, you kill a kitten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- You have parentheses problems
- In the last condition of a `cond` you should use `else`
- There's no need to use an `if` and then a `cond`, put all the conditions in a `cond`, it'll make the code clearer
- The base case in `first` is mistaken, you must return a list
- In `split` you should use `list` to build the returned list, not `cons`
- You really, really should improve the formatting of the code - parentheses should not be left alone all by themselves in a line, they're not like `{}` brackets in other programming languages - this will improve the readability of the code

With the above in mind, here's an implementation that fixes all the problems:

```
(define split
  (lambda (L)
    (if (null? L)
        '()
        (list (first L) (second L)))))

(define first
  (lambda (L)
    (cond ((null? L) '())
          ((null? (cdr L)) L)
          (else (cons (car L)
                      (first (cdr (cdr L))))))))

(define second
  (lambda (L)
    (cond ((null? L) '())
          ((null? (cdr L)) '())
          (else (cons (car (cdr L))
                      (second (cdr (cdr L))))))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
=> '((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6 8))

(split '(cat bird dog horse mouse pig tiger gerbil cow))
=> '((cat dog mouse tiger cow) (bird horse pig gerbil))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at this and remember the [Merge Sort implementation from Rosetta Code for PicoLisp](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#PicoLisp). There you only need one procedure to do both the odd and the even list and sure enough it's true for this problem as well.

```
;; makes a list of every other element
(define (alt lst)
  (if (or (null? lst)
          (null? (cdr lst)))
      lst
      (cons (car lst)
            (alt (cddr lst)))))

;; no safeguard against empty list
;; needs at least one element.
(define (split lst)
  (list (alt lst) (alt (cdr lst))))

(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)) 
; ==> ((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6 8))

(split '(cat bird dog horse mouse pig tiger gerbil cow)) 
; ==> ((cat dog mouse tiger cow) (bird horse pig gerbil))
```

To make this safe for zero elements lists is left out as an exercise.